# Change initial array value Swift

Tags: arrays, swift

I am trying to change the initial array value but I am not certain of how to do it.

Example:

```
var players = ["Peter", "John", "Michael"]
var rules = ["\(players.randomElement()!) has to run", "\(players.randomElement()!) is the best"]

players.removeAll()
players.append("Gina", "Martin")
print(rules)
```

And then I want it to print either Gina or Martin.

Comment: And what's wrong with your current code?

Comment: When it prints, it doesn't print either Gina or Martin. It prints one of the old values

Comment: Looks like you setting rules before append the names. Try to put rules after append

Comment: Use the debugger and view all your variables after each step of the code. You can also do the exercise yourself to see the difference between what you expect and what actually happens. You'll see the problem quickly.

Comment: The problem is, i first want it to display the initial values from players, and then i want to change the players to new values, and then print the new values.

Answer (score 0):

This is because rules does not know that players has changed their values.  you need to either re set the rules after you change the players or print the players instead of the rules

Comment: How do i re-set rules?

Comment: since rules is a var you can do rules = ["\(players.randomElement()!) has to run", "\(players.randomElement()!) is the best"]

Comment: you can also make rules a computed property so that you dont need to update rules every time the players change this articvle is very helpful: https://medium.com/@micosmin/swift-computed-properties-2a8fd9f88d6

Answer (score 0):

You need to make `rules` a computed property if you want it to pick a new `player` every time you access `rules`.

```
var players = ["Peter", "John", "Michael"]
var rules: [String] {
    return ["\(players.randomElement()!) has to run", "\(players.randomElement()!) is the best"]
}

players.removeAll()
players.append("Gina", "Martin")
print(rules)
```

Or if you simply want to automatically refresh `rules` based on the new `players` if `players` is updated, you can add a property observer to `players`.

```
var rules = [String]()
var players = ["Peter", "John", "Michael"] {
    didSet {
        if players.count > 0 {
            rules = ["\(players.randomElement()!) has to run", "\(players.randomElement()!) is the best"]
        } else {
            rules = []
        }
    }
}

rules = ["\(players.randomElement()!) has to run", "\(players.randomElement()!) is the best"]
print(rules)
players.removeAll()
players.append(contentsOf: ["Gina", "Martin"])
print(rules)
```